# Axis2 AxisFault "Content is not allowed in prolog." - How can i get the invalid XML message?

Tags: java, apache-axis

Occasionally we get invalid XML responses when calling webservices using Axis2. One reason beside others maybe a HTTP 500 on the other end, resulting in a non-XML response.

For better debugging it would be nice to log the HTTP response.

Is there any possibility to get the actual HTTP response in case of an AxisFault exception?

```
[...]
ServiceClient sender;
OperationClient mepClient;
        
sender = new ServiceClient (
    axisConfiguration,
    wsdlLocation,
    new QName (
            ns.getNamespaceURI(),
            serviceName ),
    null );

mepClient = sender.createClient (
    new QName (
            ns.getNamespaceURI(), action ) );

MessageContext messageContext = createMessageContext(method, attachments);
mepClient.addMessageContext (messageContext);

try {

    mepClient.execute(true);

} catch (AxisFault fault) {

    // the other side responded with non-xml content for some
    // reason - how to get the actual response?
}
```